# Collecting all imports inside a file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

is it a good idea to collect all import files inside a  allExports.js and than call wheneveru need from there as below? My main target is to see and control all files from one place...

it seems prety cool and clear code but is that way cause loadspeed or security with bad way? I cant be sure of that... I will be appreciate if anyone have an idea

_app.js starting like :

```
import {React,App,Head,thunk,Provider,composeWithDevTools,compose,applyMiddleware,createStore,AuthControl,MyLoading,Header,Footer,MainChat,Mystore,Languages} from 'allExports';
```

and this is allexport:

```
// SYSTEM EXPORTS START

export { default as React }     from 'react';
export { Component }            from 'react';
export { default as axios }     from 'axios';



export { default as Head }      from 'next/head';
export { default as App }       from 'next/app';
export { default as Image }     from 'next/image';
export { default as Link }      from 'next/link';
export { default as Script }    from 'next/script';


export { default as thunk }     from 'redux-thunk';

export { Provider }             from 'react-redux';
export { connect }              from 'react-redux';
export { composeWithDevTools }  from 'redux-devtools-extension';
export { compose,applyMiddleware,legacy_createStore as createStore} from 'redux';

// Stores
export { chatStatus,updateUser,getMyUsers } from 'store/actions/rootaction';




// SYSTEM EXPORTS FINISH AND USER EXPORT START

export { default as Mystore }       from 'store/store';
export { default as AuthControl }   from 'Middleware/AuthControl';

export { default as MyChat }        from 'a-my-npms/my-chat/MyChatContainer';
export { default as ChatButton }    from 'a-my-npms/my-chat/myChatButton';

export { default as ModalBox }      from 'a-my-npms/my-modal';

export { default as Myinput }       from 'a-my-npms/my-forms';
export { default as MyForm }        from 'a-my-npms/my-forms/myForm';

export { default as MyLoading }     from 'components/loading';
export { default as Header }        from 'components/Main/header';
export { default as Footer }        from 'components/Main/footer';
export { default as Login }         from 'components/Logged-out/login';
export { default as Register }      from 'components/Logged-out/register';
export { default as MainChat }      from 'components/chatHolders/mainPage';

export { default as Changelang }    from 'components/languages/changelang';
export { default as Languages }     from 'components/languages/languages';


// USER EXPORT DONE AND STYLE EXPORTS START

export { default as regisPStyle }   from 'styles/pages/regisPStyle.module.scss';
export { default as mainPStyle }    from 'styles/pages/mainPStyle.module.scss';

export { default as chatHoldersCss }    from 'styles/components/chatHolders.module.scss';
export { default as mainLoadingCss }    from 'styles/components/mainLoading.module.scss';
export { default as mainFootersCss }    from 'styles/components/mainFooters.module.scss';
export { default as mainHeadersCss }    from 'styles/components/mainHeaders.module.scss';
export { default as socialStyleCss }    from 'styles/components/socialStyle.module.scss';
export { default as regisCStyleCss }    from 'styles/components/regisCStyle.module.scss';
export { default as chatCoStyleCss }    from 'styles/components/chatComStyle.module.scss';

export { default as myFormMainCss }     from 'styles/components/myFormMain.module.scss';
export { default as myFormSelecCss }    from 'styles/components/myFormSelect.module.scss';
export { default as myFormSocalCss }    from 'styles/components/myFormSocial.module.scss';

export { default as myModalIconsCss }   from 'styles/components/myModalIcons.module.scss';
export { default as myModalModalCss }   from 'styles/components/myModalModal.module.scss';
export { default as myModalToastCss }   from 'styles/components/myModalToast.module.scss';


//IMAGES

export { default as myLogo }            from 'public/logos/logoShadowed.png';
export { default as myRegisterBackGround }            from 'public/images/background_regster.png';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can do lazyloading, it can be used, but otherwise the sources of pages z, y, a, b for page x will also be imported.

Comment: what u mean with lazyloading.. can u give an example?

Comment: lazy loading is to load a resource as soon as you use it. For example you have auth, product and category pages. In the current situation, while your application is on the product page, you can view the components, styles, etc. of the auth, product and category pages. is loading. However, if you do lazy loading, only the resources of the product page will be loaded while on the product page. And this causes the page to load and run faster. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading

Comment: you mean that ? --> const Home = React.lazy(() => import('./Home'));

Comment: actually it would be better if you add and example inside your answer about how to do with my question... But thanks anyway.